# In React, how to bind an input's value when rendering a list of inputs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setstate, array.prototype.map

I'm rendering a list of inputs and I want to bind each input's value to a link's href. My current attempt renders `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=undefined`:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  tweets = [
    { id: 1, link: 'example.com' },
    { id: 2, link: 'example2.com' }
  ];

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.tweets.map(tweet => 
          <div key={tweet.id}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="text" onChange={e => tweet.text = e.target.value} />
            <a href={`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${tweet.text}`}>Tweet</a>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This probably needs to involve `setState` but I have no idea how to achieve that when rendering a list. I've tried to do some research on this but didn't found anything helpful.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nunoarruda/u5c21wj9/3/

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to save the text from the input in the state (using setState), not in the tweets array. Then you can render it with something like {this.state.tweetsText[tweet.id]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the tweets variable to the state to maintain consistency in that array.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props)
    this.state = {
     tweets: [
       { id: 1, link: 'example.com' },
        { id: 2, link: 'example2.com' }
      ]
    };
  };
  
  setTweets = index => e => {
   const { tweets } = this.state
    tweets[index].text = e.target.value
    this.setState({ tweets })
  }

  render() {
   const { tweets } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        {tweets.map((tweet, index) => 
          <div key={tweet.id}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="text" onChange={this.setTweets(index)} />
            <a href={`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${tweet.text}`}>Tweet</a>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Updated Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u5c21wj9/6/

Comment: Great, exactly what I wanted. Can you explain `index => e =>`? How come the event object `e` is passed to `setTweets` if its not referenced in `onChange`?

Answer (score 1):

You can reach the desired result using `state`.

```
return (
  <div>
     {tweets.map(({ id, link }) => 
       <div key={id}>
         <input type="text" placeholder="text" onChange={({ target }) => this.setState({ [id]: target.value })} />
         <a href={`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${this.state[id] || link}`}>Tweet</a>
       </div>
     )}
   </div>
);
```

**Note**: I would move `tweets` outside the component and implement few ES6 features.

Updated Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u5c21wj9/7/

Answer (score 0):

You really should use a state here and make your `tweets` variable be part of it. To do that, add a constructor:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    tweets: [
      { id: 1, link: 'example.com' },
      { id: 2, link: 'example2.com' }
    ]
  };
}
```

Then you need to mutate each `link`whenever you type in one of the inputs. There are a few pitfalls here, so let me go through them one-by-one:

```
changeTweet = (id, e) => {
  let arr = this.state.tweets.slice();
  let index = arr.findIndex(i => i.id === id);
  let obj = Object.assign({}, arr[index]);
  obj.link = e.target.value;
  arr[index] = obj;
  this.setState({tweets: arr});
}
```

First, you need to create a copy of your state variable. This gives you something to work with, without mutating the state directly which is anti-pattern. This can be done with `slice()`.

Since you are sending in the `id` of the object to modify, we need to find it in our array (in case the items are unordered). This is done with `findIndex()`. You might want to handle the scenario in which such index is not found (I have not done that).

Now we know where in the array the object with the given `id` key is. Now, create a copy of that item (which is an object). This is also to prevent mutating the state directly. Do this with `Object.assign()`.

Now change the `link` to the input value we typed in. Replace the old item object with the new one (`obj`) and replace the old `tweets` array with the new one (`arr`).

---

Here's the full example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {      
  constructor() {
    super();
   this.state = {
     tweets: [
        { id: 1, link: 'example.com' },
        { id: 2, link: 'example2.com' }
      ]
    };
  }
  
  changeTweet = (id, e) => {
    let arr = this.state.tweets.slice();
    let index = arr.findIndex(i => i.id === id);
    let obj = Object.assign({}, arr[index]);
    obj.link = e.target.value;
    arr[index] = obj;
   this.setState({tweets: arr});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.tweets.map(tweet => 
          <div key={tweet.id}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="text" onChange={(e) => this.changeTweet(tweet.id, e)} />
            <a href={`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${tweet.link}`}>Tweet</a>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the text from the input in the state (using setState), not in the tweets array. Then you can render it getting the text from the state.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  tweets = [
    { id: 1, link: 'example.com' },
    { id: 2, link: 'example2.com' }
  ];

  state = {
    tweetsText :{}
  }

  handleTextChange = (event, tweetId) => {
     const tweetsTextCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state.tweetsText)
    tweetsTextCopy[tweetId] = event.target.value
    this.setState({tweetsText: tweetsTextCopy})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.tweets.map(tweet => 
          <div key={tweet.id}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="text" onChange={e => this.handleTextChange(e, tweet.id)} />
            <a href={`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${this.state.tweetsText[tweet.id]}`}>Tweet</a>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Links info is in the `link` property of your tweets array. The property `text` is not defined.
So, your render function should look like this

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.tweets.map(tweet => 
          <div key={tweet.id}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="text" onChange={e => tweet.text= e.target.value} />
            <a href={`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${tweet.link}`}>Tweet</a>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but that not what I'm trying to achieve. The text property is unset initially because it will be manually entered in the input by the user: onChange={e => tweet.text = e.target.value}